# Android Client not able to connect to a server

Tags: android, sockets, client-server

I have a server running on my computer and I would like my android app to connect to it. In other words, I would like to write an Android client that establishes a TCP connection, writes  something to the server and listens for responses from the server. Below is the client code:

```
public class Text extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        String fromServer, ToServer, filename;
        BufferedReader inFromServer;
        PrintWriter outToServer;
        Socket clientSocket;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try 
        {
        clientSocket = new Socket("86.36.32.251", 8000);
        outToServer  = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
        inFromServer = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        filename = "profile.txt";
        ToServer = Reader.readFileAsString(filename);
        ToServer += "\n";

        outToServer.println(ToServer);

        while((fromServer = inFromServer.readLine()) != null)
        {
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(fromServer);
            setContentView(tv);
        }

        inFromServer.close();
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

However, when I run my application, the application does not establish a TCP connection to my server. I don't know what the problem might be. I have gone through the following link http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/ which discusses the client-side of socket programming and I feel I have all the main steps in my client. Could someone please help me resolving the issue. Thanks

Comment: are you using the emulator for testing?

Comment: Did you add the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission to your manifest file?

Comment: When you say "does not establish a TCP connection", what does it mean? Does it mean that the server or the client is throwing exception? Or, are you saying you don't get any response after sending a request to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you've added the internet permission.
If you did, run this on a real device.
If it still doesn't work, paste the logcat.

Comment: I had forgotten to add the INTERNET permission so I did add it but the client is still unable to establish a connection to the server. Neither the client nor the server throws an exception. It's just that the server, which usually prints the IP address of the client just connect and process the message sent by the client, does not even print the IP address. I am using Dev phone 2, android version 2.3. Here's what eclipse prints on the console when I run the app:

Comment: [2011-08-24 10:51:38 - TextApp] ------------------------------
[2011-08-24 10:51:38 - TextApp] Android Launch!
[2011-08-24 10:51:38 - TextApp] adb is running normally.
[2011-08-24 10:51:38 - TextApp] Performing com.example.textapp.Text activity launch
[2011-08-24 10:51:38 - TextApp] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.

Comment: [2011-08-24 10:51:41 - TextApp] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2011-08-24 10:51:41 - TextApp] Device API version is 10 (Android 2.3.4)
[2011-08-24 10:51:41 - TextApp] Uploading TextApp.apk onto device 'HT0C5P800531'
[2011-08-24 10:51:41 - TextApp] Installing TextApp.apk...
[2011-08-24 10:51:43 - TextApp] Success!
[2011-08-24 10:51:43 - TextApp] Starting activity com.example.textapp.Text on device HT0C5P800531

Comment: [2011-08-24 10:51:43 - TextApp] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.textapp/.Text }

Comment: Do I have to specify a minimum API level for this app to work?

Comment: I have changed to app properties so as to require a minimum SDK of 7. I was hoping that this would be the problem but it's not. The server is still not receiving a TCP connection request.